# tunctl complains that device or resource is busy if used in /etc/qemu-ifup script

Tags: qemu

I have a following `/etc/qemu-ifup` script which is executed when I start `/usr/bin/qemu-system-i386` binary:

```shell
#!/bin/sh

set -x

switch=br0

if [ -n "$1" ];then
        /usr/sbin/tunctl -u `whoami` -t $1
        /sbin/ip link set dev $1 up
        sleep 0.5s
        /sbin/brctl addif $switch $1
        exit 0
else
        echo "Error: no interface specified"
        exit 1
fi
```

The problem is, that `tunctl` complains that device or resource is busy:

```
root@VM-host:~# qemu -hda /root/1.raw -device e1000,netdev=net0,mac=DE:AD:BE:EF:69:01 -netdev tap,id=net0 -display vnc=:1
+ switch=br0
+ [ -n tap0 ]
+ whoami
+ /usr/sbin/tunctl -u root -t tap0
TUNSETIFF: Device or resource busy
+ /sbin/ip link set dev tap0 up sleep 0.5s
Error: either "dev" is duplicate, or "sleep" is a garbage.
+ /sbin/brctl addif br0 tap0
+ exit 0
```

When I execute simply the `/usr/sbin/tunctl -u root -t tap0`, then `tap0` is created without any issues:

```
root@VM-host:~# /usr/sbin/tunctl -u root -t tap0
Set 'tap0' persistent and owned by uid 0
root@VM-host:~#
```

Any ideas what causes such behavior?

Answer (score 3):

(I dont know from when),
qemu will create the tap first and then call your `/etc/qemu-ifup` script.
So you see the error report,
just because the same tap already exists.

Reference: qemu source: `net/tap-linux.c` (check the function: `tap_open()`).

Answer (score 0):

The error message `"Error: either "dev" is duplicate, or "sleep" is a garbage"` tells the cause of your problem.

Should use the following command to bring up the tap interface:

```
/sbin/ip link set $1 up
```